# How can i calculate a matrix of correlation?

Tags: correlation, music

I want to implement my own music algorithm detecting an angle of arrival of non-stationary signal and I need to make a matrix of correlation of this signal. I have problem because I don't know how to calculate expected value of product of signal and transposition of this signal.

$$ R_s= E[s(t)s^H(t)] $$

Comment: how many sensors do you have?

Comment: I have 10 sensors.

Comment: what is the duration of your signal?

Comment: Now I'm making a simulation and its duration is 100 seconds.

Comment: music is a narrow band algorithm. is your simulation narrow band?

Comment: I think so. I generate a sine signal and send it to array which gather this signal.